Artifactory OSS won't start, log shows "Failed executing GetEntitlements, Server responded with an invalid status 404 UNIMPLEMENTED"
I just installed Artifactory OSS 7.84.15 on a Windows Server 2019 IBM cloud machine. I only changed 4 options: I changed 2 default ports that conflict with other Tomcat installs on this machine, I changed the database used to the embedded Derby because this is just a proof of concept, and I configured the IP to 127.0.0.1 because I saw it use an IPv6 address somewhere during troubleshooting and I read on a different question that might cause issues.
When starting Artifactory, whether that's as a service or from the artifactory.bat file, after a minute or two of waiting I end up with the below error in my log output:
2024-06-24T07:59:46.763Z [1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m [                ] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:60       ] [jf-common-pool-2    ] - Uncaught exception.
org.jfrog.jfconnect.client.exception.JFConnectClientException: Could not init the client
    at org.jfrog.jfconnect.client.EntitlementsClientImpl.init(EntitlementsClientImpl.java:36)
    at org.jfrog.jfconnect.client.JFConnectClientImpl.init(JFConnectClientImpl.java:63)
    at org.jfrog.access.server.service.license.EntitlementsService.lambda$init$1(EntitlementsService.java:59)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.jfrog.jfconnect.client.exception.RetryFailedException: org.jfrog.common.ExecutionFailed: Failed executing GetEntitlements, last error [Server responded with an invalid status, [localhost:8046]. Status code: [UNIMPLEMENTED]. Description [HTTP status code 404
invalid content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
headers: Metadata(:status=404,content-type=text/plain; charset=utf-8,x-content-type-options=nosniff,date=Mon, 24 Jun 2024 07:59:46 GMT,content-length=19)
DATA-----------------------------
404 page not found
]. Err [UNIMPLEMENTED: HTTP status code 404
invalid content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
headers: Metadata(:status=404,content-type=text/plain; charset=utf-8,x-content-type-options=nosniff,date=Mon, 24 Jun 2024 07:59:46 GMT,content-length=19)
DATA-----------------------------
404 page not found
]]. Will not retry anymore.
    at org.jfrog.jfconnect.client.grpc.GrpcRetryableCallSupplier.executeWithRetry(GrpcRetryableCallSupplier.java:37)
    at org.jfrog.jfconnect.client.grpc.GrpcClient.executeWithRetryAndConfig(GrpcClient.java:132)
    at org.jfrog.jfconnect.client.grpc.GrpcClient.getEntitlementsUntilSucceed(GrpcClient.java:122)
    at org.jfrog.jfconnect.client.EntitlementsAutoUpdatingCache.updateEntitlements(EntitlementsAutoUpdatingCache.java:120)
    at org.jfrog.jfconnect.client.EntitlementsAutoUpdatingCache.init(EntitlementsAutoUpdatingCache.java:46)
    at org.jfrog.jfconnect.client.EntitlementsClientImpl.init(EntitlementsClientImpl.java:34)
    ... 5 common frames omitted

I've tried Googling this error and I didn't find anything relevant. The weird thing is that earlier on the day, I tried to use Artifactory Pro, and that would start without any problems. Reason I stopped using it was because we didn't have a Pro license to install and we had to swap to the OSS version.

From the log snippet provided, the JFconnect micro-service seems to have failed to start.
As far as I know, this service should not block Artifactory from loading and starting, but rather just show the expected exception. If Artifactory is failing to start this is a potential bug.
Regardless, I would recommend you check if disabling this microservice resolves your issue. You can do that by editing the system.yaml configuration file:
jfconnect:
   enabled: false


I've disabled that service and artifactory boots up correctly now. I'm not sure if the service really caused it to not work, because before I disabled that service it would reach the login window. When I tried logging in on that page earlier it would apparently hang. But now that the jfconnect service is disabled, logging in works and the onboarding wizard appears.

I looked some more at the default system.yaml full file, and it appears that the default port for jfconnect is set to 8030. But if that's the case, then why did artifactory try to contact it on port 8046?

The JFrog Platform uses two types of ports:


Internal Ports (8046,8030, 8040, etc..) - These ports are given to each microservice and are used for internal communication with other microservices within the same node/VM.


External Ports (8081 and 8082) - Specific ports for Router and Artifactory microservices. (Yes. Artifactory is also the name of the platform's main product and a specific microservice within the Artifactory application). You can read more about the ports here (https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/artifactory-network-ports)



As for your question about communicating with the Router (https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/jfrog-router-service) please allow me to explain.
The router is a built-in reverse proxy that redirects requests to the right microservice. In addition, it performs routing health checks against all the other microservices and knows whether the other microservices are available.
This explains the communication from Artifactory to the Router.

Further adding for visibility - The error you received is from the Access microservice as can be seen by the "jfac" as the microservice identifier log.
Access has tried to communicate with the JFconnect microservice and caught the exception. We can see it tried a few times and eventually gave up.
During that time the Router microservice is trying to send health checks that are failing which can explain the mentioned communication with the 8046 port.

I see. One last question: what is the jfconnect service and can I just leave it disabled for now? From what I understand it has to do with what the connected license is allowed to do, but because I use the OSS version, I'm fairly sure there is no license involved.

You are correct. JFconnect is an entitlements service which enables dynamic entitlement allocation for the connected products, based on account/subscription. Since you are using OSS version, no license is used so this service can be disabled. I think the issue observed will always happen with the OSS version and could be a potential bug.

Where should I report a bug like that for triage?

You can open a bug for this issue in JFrog’s public JIRA https://jfrog.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/RTFACT/issues. You can register first here https://id.atlassian.com/signup?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fid.atlassian.com%2Fjoin%2Fuser-access%3Fresource%3Dari%253Acloud%253Ajira%253A%253Asite%252F2f558c84-4b59-43c2-b64c-20812a111877%26continue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fjfrog.atlassian.net%252Fjira%252Fsoftware%252Fc%252Fprojects%252FRTFACT%252F&application=jira
